# ¿Cómo creo un zip a partir de un arreglo de int?

Tags: java, file, zip

Tengo un método que me regresa un arreglo de enteros, es un archivo zip desde un repositorio utilizando URLConnection.

```
int[] fileZip = objlUtilityManagerInterface.getNoticeFile(img.get(2), img.get(0)+img.get(1)+File.separator);
                        System.out.println(fileZip.length);
```

Hasta aquí esa línea me imprimte 315850 que es la longitud del arreglo, o sea, mi zip convertido en un arreglo de ints.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es crear físicamente ese zip en una carpeta de mi pc. Lo intento hacer con el siguiente código, el cuál sí me crea el .zip donde debe de ir pero no puedo abrirlo, parece que no está bien creado. Al tratar de abrirlo con winrar este me dice que el archivo tiene un formato desconocido o está dañado.

Primero convierto el arreglo de enteros a arreglo de bytes y después creo el archivo zip

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(fileZip.length * 4);        
                     IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
                     intBuffer.put(fileZip);

                     byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();

                     FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(Tools.obtenerRutaAplicacion()
                                + separator+"temp"+separator+img.get(1)+separator+img.get(2));

                     try {
                            stream.write(array);
                        } finally {
                            stream.close();
                        }
```

Este código me crea esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero no puedo abrirlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué estoy haciendo mal, qué me hace falta hacer?

Comment: un arreglo de enteros.. no sera un arreglo de bytes?? si es un arreglo de enteros, en que codificacion estan.. porque una cosa es ver al entero como numero y otra como bytes... es raro que sea un arreglo de enteros.. estas lleno de numeros negativos?

Comment: Touché. Debe ser arreglo de bytes, dices. Qué tal si ese lo combierto a arreglo de bytes y luego trato?... letme try

Comment: No ps no, no funcionó. Es que así me lo regresa el servicio ese, en un arreglo de enteros, se supone que ese arreglo de enteros es el zip, pero lo quiero crear en mi local pero no puedo s:

Comment: no tengo ni idea que hace bufferedwritter.. pero dime que no graba archivos de texto si no que graba archivos binarios.. y que cada numero lo transformas a byte...

Comment: Es cierto, gbianchi. He cambiado el código hacia el, según yo, correcto y he actualizado el post. Sería de gran ayuda si le echas un vistazo por favor.

Comment: Cada entero lo transformas a 4 bytes?

Comment: Ya lo resolví, ahorita actualizo el post

Answer (score 0):

Esto me funcionó. Parece ser que la manera en que convertía el arreglo de enteros al de bytes no era la indicada.

```
int[] fileZip = objlUtilityManagerInterface.getNoticeFile(img.get(2), img.get(0)+img.get(1)+File.separator);
                        System.out.println(fileZip.length);

                        byte[] bytesSalida = null;
                        int[] intSalida;
                        Integer auxObjInt;
                        int cont = 0;
                        bytesSalida = new byte[fileZip.length];
                        while(cont < fileZip.length){
                            auxObjInt= fileZip[cont];
                            bytesSalida[cont]=auxObjInt.byteValue();
                            cont++;
                        }

                         FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(Tools.obtenerRutaAplicacion()
                                    + separator+"temp"+separator+img.get(1)+separator+img.get(2));

                         try {
                                stream.write(bytesSalida);
                            } finally {
                                stream.close();
                            }
```